# Some of my product price options have disappeared on the admin side

Tags: magento-1.8, product, admin, price

If I go to the magento admin panel, the pricing options are limited. I don't know where the conflict is coming from.

I've attached two screen shots. One of what it should be, one of what it is. Any ideas?

I've attached two screen shots, first is what it is, second is what it should be.

[image: what it is]

[image: what it should be]

Answer (score 1):

It likely has to do with product type. Ref [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Msrp`](https://github.com/wlvrn/magento-community/blob/1.8.1.0/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Msrp.php#L37):

```
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Msrp extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Boolean
{
/**
 * Disable MAP if it's bundle with dynamic price type
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 * @return bool
 */
public function beforeSave($product)
{
    if (!($product instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)
        || $product->getTypeId() != Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_BUNDLE
        || $product->getPriceType() != Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Price::PRICE_TYPE_DYNAMIC
    ) {
        return parent::beforeSave($product);
    }

    parent::beforeSave($product);
    $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
    $value = $product->getData($attributeCode);
    if (empty($value)) {
        $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->isMsrpApplyToAll();
    }
    if ($value) {
        $product->setData($attributeCode, 0);
    }
    return $this;
}
}
```